# Converting multiple date rows to columns in Python/R/PowerBI?

Tags: python, r, powerbi

I have a dataset which has 1 million values of a particular order. The problem is that since each order has multiple dates in rows, the values are duplicated. I want to show all the change dates for one order in a row instead of showing in multiple rows.

I tried using pivovt in Python and using Pivot in PowerBI. The pivot in PowerBI does convert the dates to columns (but as headers). Also it does not remove duplicates. Instead of that it shows 0 for each columns as rows.

I want to have something like this:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fS3iG.png)

Answer (score 0):

with R here is the approach.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 = df %>% select(-Delivery_Date) %>% 
  group_by(GR_Key) %>% 
  mutate(GroupOrder = seq(n())) %>% # Create row order
  spread(GroupOrder, Customer_Need_Date, sep="_") 

df2 = df %>% select(-Customer_Need_Date) %>% 
  group_by(GR_Key) %>% 
  mutate(GroupOrder = seq(n())) %>% 
  spread(GroupOrder, Delivery_Date, sep="_")

df_final = df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by="GR_Key")
```

Now this should get you what you need

Comment: i am getting this error: "Error in df %>% select(-Delivery_Date) %>% group_by(GR_Key) %>% mutate(GroupOrder = seq(n())) %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%""

Comment: It is called the pipe symbol and comes from the package magrittr. Other pieces of the code uses dplyr package. The package tidyverse has both and so you can use library(tidyverse)

Comment: Hi, I believe i just want to know how you used spread for this function? I will really appreciate if you could header for the spread function like (Data = df, key, value).

Comment: and I believe you wanted to select (Customer Need Date) instead of Delivery Date